# How do I add transition to styles changed on mouseover and mouseout events

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I changed styles on anchor tags and icons I want to add a transition to them and I don't know how.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li");
const icons = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li i");
const visitButtons = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a.visit--link");

listItems.forEach((item, id) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    icons[id].style.display = "none";
    visitButtons[id].style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    visitButtons[id].style.display = "inline-block";
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    icons[id].style.display = "inline-block";
    visitButtons[id].style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    visitButtons[id].style.display = "none";
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 2s;
}

nav ul li i {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
}

nav ul li i,
nav ul li a {
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 15px;
}

nav ul li a.visit--link {
  background-color: #80d6ff;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Sliding Sidebar</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02de928ecb.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <h2>MOST POPULAR CASINOS</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>MUCHO VEGAS</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>LOKI</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>GOLDEN STAR</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>BITSTARY</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>GUNSBET</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I am adding a Visit link at mouseover on list items and hide the icons. On `mouseout` I'm hiding the link and showing the icons. I thought that just adding transition 1s to anchor tags would add the transition to all styling changes on anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `display: none` when you want to transition the element because it will ignore all transitions and animations, instead you can use `opacity: 0` and `width: 0` or move it outside screen view using `transform` property:

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li");
const icons = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li i");
const visitButtons = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a.visit--link");

listItems.forEach((item, id) => {
  item.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    icons[id].style.transform = "translateX(-100px)"; // to move it outside screen
    icons[id].style.width = 0; // remove width for the text next to it to move in place of it
    visitButtons[id].style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    visitButtons[id].style.opacity = 1; // fade in
  });
  item.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    icons[id].style.transform = "translate(0)"; // return it to it's initial position
    icons[id].style.width = "auto"; // add width back to icon
    visitButtons[id].style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    visitButtons[id].style.opacity = 0; // unfade, hide
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sliding Sidebar</title>
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02de928ecb.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <style>
      nav {
        width: 40%;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column; 
        overflow: hidden; /* this is needed for the visit text to not show up outside the nav when entering the screen  */
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px 30px;
      }
      nav ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      nav ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        transition: all 1s;
      }
      nav ul li i {
        margin: 0px 5px;
        transition: all 1s;
      }
      nav ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0;
        color: #000;
      }
      nav ul li i,
      nav ul li a {
        font-size: 36px;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      nav ul li a.visit--link {
        background-color: #80d6ff;
        color: #fff;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 1s;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <h2>MOST POPULAR CASINOS</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#"
              ><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>MUCHO VEGAS</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#"
              ><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>LOKI</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#"
              ><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>GOLDEN STAR</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#"
              ><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>BITSTARY</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>
            <a href="#"
              ><i class="fa-brands fa-fantasy-flight-games"></i>GUNSBET</a
            >
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="visit--link">VISIT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```